# Move HTML Table Cell up or down (not row)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-table

I am working on a project where I have an HTML table and I need to offer users the option to swap two HTML table cells content.

Specifically, a user can click to select a row, then choose to move that row up or down. Really, they are only moving the content of column 2, which represents the information. Column 1 represents order, which will **not** change.

The table will be two total columns.
Column 1 will represent linear order (i.e. 1-10), it will not change.
Column 2 will be database-provided information (in the example code I provided last name).

I have built two buttons, up and down, and utilized two Javascript functions that allow a user to select a row and move it up or down.

The current code *successfully moves a whole row to go up or down*, but ***I only need the cell contents of column 2 to go up or down***.

Please take a look at the provided code and JSFiddle and let me know how I can solve this? Thanks in advance!

```js
var index; // variable to set the selected row index
function getSelectedRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
      // clear the selected from the previous selected row
      // the first time index is undefined
      if (typeof index !== "undefined") {
        table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
      }

      index = this.rowIndex;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");

    };
  }

}
getSelectedRow();

function upNdown(direction) {
  var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows,
    parent = rows[index].parentNode;

  if (direction === "up") {
    if (index > 1) {
      parent.insertBefore(rows[index], rows[index - 1]);
      // when the rowgo up the index will be equal to index - 1
      index--;
    }
  }

  if (direction === "down") {
    if (index < rows.length - 1) {
      parent.insertBefore(rows[index + 1], rows[index]);
      // when the row go down the index will be equal to index + 1
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  color: #17bb1c;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
    <meta content="30" http-equiv="refresh">

    <title> {{.Title}} </title>

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }

    </style>


  </head>

  <body>

    <header>

    </header>



    <main>


      <table id="table" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Order</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Roberts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Davis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
      <button onclick="upNdown('down');">&ShortDownArrow;</button>


    </main>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

> [***Link to JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Woftsare/1L06s82z/12/)

Comment: So you mean to work it like, consider there are 2 items in 4th and 5th rows. You just need the second column value to be swapped. (First column is in linear order, say row number etc), right ?

Comment: I have not looked at your code, but the question makes me wonder, can you not copy the *contents* to a new cell, instead of trying to 'move a cell'?

Comment: @AbinThaha Yes, column 1 will essentially be in row number order. I only need the contents of column 2 to be changed. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @wazz Yes, I am open to copying the contents and I have researched InnerHTML but I am having trouble using it to grab column 2. Note: I will not know how many rows I have. So, I could not, for example, just simply swap the contents of id=td1 and id=td2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer makes changes the posted code for simplicity (at least on the surface) and to prevent moving the header row down the table using the buttons:

- A reference to the selected row is held rather than an index.
- In HTML, the header row has been placed within a `thead` element, and the data rows within a `tbody` element (important in code).
- When moving a row, the order of two rows is reversed, and then the `textContent` of their first cells swapped - without moving the "order" column cells to different rows. If this is too simple you could swap the `innerHTML` property of the cells instead.
- Whilst making changes, clicking a row a second time was used to deselect it: clicking outside the table would be another thing you could monitor, as you wish.

```js
"use strict";
const tbody = document.querySelector("#table tbody");
let selected = null;
tbody.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  let row = e.target.closest("tr");
  if( row === selected) {
    row.classList.toggle("selected")
    selected = null;
  }
  else {
    if(selected) {
      selected.classList.toggle("selected");
    }
    selected = row;
    row.classList.toggle("selected");
  }
});

function upNdown( direction) {
  let up, down;
  if( selected) {
    up  =  direction == "up" ? selected : selected.nextElementSibling;
    down = direction == "up" ? selected.previousElementSibling : selected;
    if( up && down) {
      tbody.insertBefore(up, down); // put up before down
      var temp = up.firstElementChild.textContent; // swap first cells' text content
      up.firstElementChild.textContent = down.firstElementChild.textContent;
      down.firstElementChild.textContent = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Roberts</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Davis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
<button onclick="upNdown('down');">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer. This is what I was looking for. I don't have enough reputation to upvote but I would if I could. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

It depends on exactly what you want. You mention having tried moving innerHTML so this snippet does that - leaving any attributes on the two tds unmoved (see Note below):

```js
var index; // variable to set the selected row index
function getSelectedRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
      // clear the selected from the previous selected row
      // the first time index is undefined
      if (typeof index !== "undefined") {
        table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
      }

      index = this.rowIndex;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");

    };
  }

}
getSelectedRow();

function upNdown(direction) {
  var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows,
    parent = rows[index].parentNode;

  if (direction === "up") {
    if (index > 1) {
      // get the relevant cell which is the second one as we know only tds are the children
      let td = rows[index].children[1];
      let tdAbove = rows[index - 1].children[1];
      let temp = td.innerHTML;
      td.innerHTML = tdAbove.innerHTML;
      tdAbove.innerHTML = temp;
      // when the rowgo up the index will be equal to index - 1
      index--;
    }
  }

  if (direction === "down") {
    if (index < rows.length - 1) {
      let td = rows[index].children[1];
      let tdBelow = rows[index + 1].children[1];
      let temp = td.innerHTML;
      td.innerHTML = tdBelow.innerHTML;
      tdBelow.innerHTML = temp;
      // when the row go down the index will be equal to index + 1
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}

tr {
  cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
  color: #17bb1c;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>

  </header>



  <main>


    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Roberts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Davis</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
    <button onclick="upNdown('down');">&ShortDownArrow;</button>


  </main>
```

Note: in the question the idea of moving a whole element, not just its contents, is introduced. You could do that instead of swapping the contents (i.e. all the attributes would also get moved) by using for example outerHTML. However, this may not be what you want because there may be for example an inline style on the top element which highlights it in gold if this is a leader board. It depends on exactly what your requirement is.

Note also that the snippet assumes the table is well-formed in the sense that there are no non-td elements as direct children within the selectable rows.